# Installation of MySQL 5.7 issue on Centos 7-directory initialization issue

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7

While installing MySQL 5.7 on centos7, I am struggling with the data directory initialization step:

```
bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
```

I am getting an error as

```
bin/mysqld:Error on realpath on 'var\lib\mysql-files'
Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and  is accessible by MYSQL server.Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
```

.

Please suggest.

Comment: did you check the permissions of that directory ?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the  [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv),

`/var/lib/mysql-files` is the (default) directory where mysql allows import/export operations to work only with files, and the directory MUST exist.

You could try either:

- Make sure the directory exists and give access to mysql

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql-files
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-files
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/lib/mysql-files
```

Or:

- Disable this option from `my.cnf`

Comment: Just edited the first command from touch -> mkdir (mysql-files is a directory not a file)